# Count segments where A[i] is rightmost or leftmost and is max

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array containing `N` integers and you have to answer `K` queries. Each query contains an integer `X` which is the index of the (1 based index) element of the array.
Calculate the following for each query:

```
The number of segments containing the index X as the leftmost or the 
rightmost element and the number at the index `X` is `>=` each element
of that segment.
```

Segment formation example:
You have array `{1, 2, 3}`.
The possible segments for `3` are `[2,3]` and `[1,2,3]` and `[3]`.
The possible segments for 2 are `[2]` and `[1,2]`
I got solution by brute force. Worst case Time Complexity is `O(n * k)`

```
Input: Array[] = {4,2,1,3}, Queries[] = {1,4}
Output:  
4  
3

Explanation: 
For first query 1 all possible valid segments are [4], [4,2] , [4,2,1] and [4,2,1,3] 
hence answer is 4.  
For second query 4 all possible valid segments are [3], [1,3] and [2,1,3]
hence answer is 3.
```

Comment: Dude I didn't even understand the question....can you help me out here?

Comment: What part didn't you understand?

Comment: yea now I understand...the A[i] part wasn't clear in the description part once i look at the title it cleared up. One question though if we sort the array e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 and lets say the question was for 4 and A[4] is 4 in the original array so ans would be 4 only right? I can count the digits left of A[i] including A[i]

Comment: No sorting doesn't work. See accepted answer

Comment: Why sorting doesn't work though? I don't understand the accepted answer

Comment: When you sort array data shuffle that changes the count of our ans. For Eg. take array = {3,4,5,1,2} and Query = 2. Correct answer is 2. But after sorting answer will be 4.

Comment: Yes I ran into the same issue that you just mentioned and for 4 seems to be correct ans just because I haven't really understood the problem.

I thought that we need to find the subset of given number at index i from the array such that the no. itself in the subset should be >= all other numbers present in that subset array. Then count all those subsets and return. Also make sure that the no. is always on rightmost or leftmost of the subset. As per this the and 4 is correct. What is that I didn't catch in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preprocess two arrays in `O(n)`, where the elements are the indexes of the next larger element for each element in the original array (one to the right and one to the left). Then answer each query in `O(1)`.

Comment: Let me tell you what I understand. Make 2 arrays left and right. In left array index i stores farthest greater element index corresponding to original array element i. Similarly for right array. Is that you are saying?

Comment: @guptashekhar54 no, I meant find for each element where is the [next greater](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element) element in the array to the right and to the left. Given [1, 2, 1, 3, 2], the "next greater" element to the right of the 2 at index 1 is the 3 at index 3. The 2 at index 1 can therefore be leftmost of all valid segments extending from it to the right until we reach 3.

Comment: Hey @גלעדברקן Can you please help me understand your approach better? I am completely lost with this question. A pseudo code would be very helpful.

Comment: @alamshahbaz16497 please see if my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026440/count-segments-where-ai-is-rightmost-or-leftmost-and-is-max#comment113229325_64027114) just above yours is enough of an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

For each query, follow steps:

1. process from 0 to index (-1 as your query is 1 index based)in query
2. process from index(-1) in query to N-1

While processing sub-arrays, check that the element at an index, say `i` should be less than or equal to element at index in your query. If yes, then you are safe to print it.